# AC simulation contradicts transient simulation in LTSPICE

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have built an integrator circuit using AD8031. In AC simulation I get 45dB while in pulse response in transient. I have  the voltage input of the opamp so it will be from 5 to -5. But still my AC simulation says that I have 45dB it's 0.001*10*10*10*10*2 but as you can see below the transient only gives me -170mV.

Why AC contradicts transient?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *the transient only gives me-170mV*

Of course; because your input is only 1 mV. In AC analysis the default assumed is 1 volt unless otherwise specified. Given the resistor values you have used, the gain is -170.

> *my AC simulation says that i have 45 dB*

That's a gain of 177 i.e. pretty close to the theoretical gain of 170.

Answer (score 1):

AC Analysis is a linearized calculation method.  The input amplitude is irrelevant, aside from scaling the output levels proportionally.  Since the input is 1V, 45dBV output can be read directly as 45dB gain.  Which matches the design and the transient result (170 gain is 44.61 dB).